# use same while loop in different functions

Tags: java

i have a pretty similar while loop in two different functions, how can i write the code that both functions use the same while? the idea is when i go in either of the functions they should implement the behavior of retrying 5 times before giving up.

```
    public Document getHtml(String url) {
        int retries = 0;
        while (retries < 5) {
            try {
                return Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                LOGGER.logWarn("Problem Occured While Downloading The File= " + e.getMessage());
            }
            retries += 1;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFile(String url) {
        int retries = 0;
        while(retries < 5) {
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                try (InputStream is = urlObj.openStream()) {
                    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
                return result.toString("UTF-8");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.logWarn("Problem Occured While Downloading The File= " + e.getMessage());
            }
            retries += 1;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see similar `while` loops in your code. I see three `while` loops that do widely different stuff.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca OP likely means refactoring  `int retries = 0; while(retries < 5) { callback(); retries += 1; }` out of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract your retry logic to a higher-order function:

```
public static <T> T retry5Times(ThrowingSupplier<T, IOException> supplier) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.logWarn("Problem Occured While Downloading The File= " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where `ThrowingSupplier` is:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<T, E extends Exception> {
    T get() throws E;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
public Document getHtml(String url) {
    return retry5Times(() -> Jsoup.connect(url).get());
}
```

Comment: thanks bananon, i think this is what i was looking for